# fixed,setprecision functions

Tags: c++, function, iomanip

why setprecision and fixed and other iomanip functions called by using cout not like the string functions for example name.find('') plz help

Answer (score 1):

They allow you to chain the operations in the manner:

`cout << setprecision(3) << 1.234 << setprecision(4) << 3.45678;`

In fact, there are functions to do that, but using them directly breaks this "streaming" capability:

```
cout.precision(3);
cout << 1.234;
cout.precision(4);
cout << 3.45678;
```

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision vs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision